# select inline jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i would like to know hot to get the select on the same line of buttons.

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/H9W2d/70/)

```
<div id="commands">
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Button</a>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Button</a>
   <select id="select-scenari" data-theme="f" data-inline="true">
       <option value="manuale">Option</option>
       <option value="fuori-casa">Option</option>
       <option value="party">Option</option>
   </select>
   <a data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
</div>
```

As you can see all buttons are on the same line (except if the window is too small) but not the select.
If you change the select to a button everything is ok.
How can i make the select to appear on the same line?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks as though `data-inline="true"` is only recognized on the `a` tags in your example. By applying the same classes to the div that wraps the select, you can achieve the same result:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9W2d/2/

Answer (score 1):

Take the select out of the div, or use a div around the buttons and one around the select and float them.